# dynamic form item in antd-form-builder

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I've used antd-form-builder to create a form. I need to add and remove a form item dynamically like this: https://ant.design/components/form#components-form-demo-dynamic-form-items

This is an example form code:

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import { Form, Button } from 'antd'
import FormBuilder from 'antd-form-builder'

export default () => {
  const handleFinish = useCallback(values => {
    console.log('Submit: ', values)
  })

  return (
    <Form layout="inline" onFinish={handleFinish}>
      <FormBuilder meta={{ key: 'username', placeholder: 'Username' }} />
      <FormBuilder meta={{ key: 'password', widget: 'password', placeholder: 'Password' }} />
      <Form.Item>
        <Button htmlType="submit" type="primary">
          Login
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  )
}
```

I want to add dynamic form item to it, like this image:

[image]

How can I do it?

thanks in forward.

Comment: Please include the code so that community members can understand what is the you need and give better answer  relevent to your problem

Comment: @Azzy I edited my question and added code and image to clarify it. :)